# Is the number of quadratic nonresidues modulo $p^2$, greater than the number of quadratic residues modulo $p^2$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Let $p$ be a prime. The number of quadratic nonresidues modulo $p^2$, is greater than the number of quadratic residues modulo $p^2$.

Is that statement true or false? Why?

Thank you.

Comment: This seems tautological. Is one of the $p^2$ supposed to be $p$ or one of the 'nonresidues' supposed to be 'residues'?

Comment: Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: How do you define quadratic residues? Some define as the squares, some define as the units that are squares.

Comment: An integer $q$ is called a quadratic residue modulo $n$ if it is congruent to a perfect square modulo $n$. That is, if there exists an integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv q$ mod($n$)- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's count the number of squares modulo $p^2$. I'll assume that $p$ is odd. The case $p=2$ is left as an exercise...

If $x^2$ is a multiple of $p$, then $x$ is a multiple of $p$, and $x^2 \equiv 0 \bmod {p^2}$.

If $x^2$ is a not multiple of $p$, then $x$ is a not multiple of $p$, and $x^2$ is a unit modulo $p^2$. There are $\phi(p^2)=p^2-p$ such units. Since there is a primitive root modulo $p^2$, half of the units are squares. Indeed, if $g$ is a primitive root, then all units are of the form $g^k$ and the squares are of the form $g^{2k}$.

So, the number of squares is $(p^2-p)/2+1$ and the number of nonsquares is $(p^2+p)/2-1$.

Alternatively, consider the map $x \mapsto x^2$ in the unit group. This map is a homomorphism and its image is the set of nonzero squares. The kernel is the set of solutions $x^2=1$, which is $\{\pm 1\}$. (There is something to prove here!) Hence the image has size $(p^2-p)/2$.

Comment: For the general case, see Stangl, ["Counting Squares in ℤn"](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/cms_upload/Walter_D22068._Stangl.pdf), Mathematics Magazine (1996) 69 (4): 285–289, as cited in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#The_number_of_quadratic_residues.

Comment: Could you please explain the sentence "Since there is a primitive root modulo $p^2$, half of the units are squares." ? Thank you

Comment: Alternatively, if $a$ is one specific nonresidue, then $x\mapsto ax$ is a bijection of nonzero residues and nonresidues. Beyond that, we still have $0$.

Comment: @Math_D, see my edited answer.